# Show Last modified tables/records Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, audit, last-modified, acts-as-audited

I still can't figure out how to implement this as i am a newbie with this. some people helpt me and said i had to use audited, so it did. this is my controller:

```
  def show

    add_breadcrumb 'Contract Bekijken', :contracten_path

    @contracten = Contracten.find(params[:id])

    @audits = @contracten.audits.collect { |a| a.created_at }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contracten }
    end
  end
```

Here's a pastie of my whole controller. http://pastie.org/4270702

But i don't know if this is right or how to implement this to my views.

I hope someone really can help because i really need this to work this week.

Thanks.

---

i have a rails app where i can store contracts in a database, it also has persons and factories tables in the database.
Now i would like to have a last modified table.

I would like when people update/add a new record to the database, that it will show the modifications in the div right on the screenshot.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a audit history of edits.

You can either implement that yourself (may make sense if there is custom business logic involved you really want to write yourself) by hooking into the [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for that model.

A sample implementation may look like this:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :audit

  def audit
    log = AuditLog.new(:user_id => current_user, :action => :update, ...)
    log.save
  end
end
```

This would assume you have a AuditLog Model that contains the appropriate fields you want to log to and in your audit method you write to that.

Or, a simpler way is to use the [Audited gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) that does that for you (but may come with some limitations).

From the documentation of Audited it seems like you can simply fetch a `Contract` record and use the `audits` on that model to then access the audited information.

Sample

```
def show
  @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
  @audits = @contract.audits.collect { |a| a.created_at }
end
```

Now you have all the timestamps of the audits in the `@audits` variable and can access them from the view using `<% @audits.each do ...`.

Comment: I only have to show the last modified records so i think the gem will to the work :D thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow :)
If the answer was helpful you usually should upvote it and mark it as answered if it solves your problem :)

Comment: i still have another question. how can i render these information into my views? so everybody can see the last modified records?

Comment: Updated the answer.. hope it helps

Comment: Maybe you should study the documentation on `Audited` a little.. You should be able to spot the error yourself .. I can't do your work for you.. I can only point you in the right direction.

Comment: yes you did :) i will read the documentation, but because i'm a noob with RoR it's a bit tricky. :) thanks

Comment: i tried serveral things but it won't work. it's also because i'm a newbie and i can't fix it with this info you gave.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you just need a list based on the updated_at field.

How about - `@contract_list = Contract.all.order( "updated_at DESC").limit(10)`

Then you can iterate over the list in the view.

Nice looking page!